# Cache control is not working in asp.net core 2.0 application

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-core, browser-cache, cache-control

I hosted a website over IIS 10 and added below section config file for cache for static contents.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" cacheControlCustom="public" />
  </staticContent>...
```

and below is startup.cs file section

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    var options = new RewriteOptions()
   .AddRedirect("rent/(.*)", "/$1")
   .AddRedirect("explore/(.*)", "/$1"); 
    app.UseRewriter(options);
    app.UseMyMiddleware();

    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
        {
            const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 7;
            ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
                "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
        }
    });
}
```

However it's not adding cache-control in response header for any static resource like images, js, css files.

Can anyone help me out? If some specific information is needed, please let me know, i'll update in question.

Comment: found the issue myself. I used app.UseStaticFiles();, empty one.

Comment: Please post that as an answer, so this question will move out of the unanswered queue.

Comment: okay @ChrisPratt

Answer (score 1):

I was calling `UseStaticFiles` function twice. Commenting default one fixed the problem.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    var options = new RewriteOptions()
   .AddRedirect("rent/(.*)", "/$1")
   .AddRedirect("explore/(.*)", "/$1"); 
    app.UseRewriter(options);
    app.UseMyMiddleware();

    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }
    //app.UseStaticFiles(); // commenting this fixed the issue.
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
        {
            const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 7;
            ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
                "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
        }
    });
}
```